# Insert files in MongoDBs GridFS

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I am trying to insert a bunch of pdf-files into MongoDB using GridFS, but get a `MongoGridFSException` with the message: error setting up file *name* in *path*, where *name* is the absolute path to the pdf-document on the file system.

I'm using a very simple CLI-script:

```
$it = new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__ .'/files');
while ($it as $file) {
    $grid->storeFile($file->getPathname(), array('metadata' => $metadata));
}
```

I find the lack of documentation for GridFS disturbing. The examples in [MongoGridFS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongogridfs.php) and [storeFile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongogridfs.storefile.php) all just show a simple filename as first argument; if the data is retrieved from this filename, what basePath does the script assume (`cwd`, `__DIR__` or something completely different?) or can I just add the absolute path (judging from the error message, probably not)?

I was contemplating on using `storeBytes(file_get_contents($file->getPathname())` instead, but then how do I retrieve the file, when there is no filename associated with it? Do I add the filename in the 2nd argument (options-array)?

Also, if I want to know the mine/type of a stored file, do I have to specify it in the metadata manually or is this determined automatically when inserting the file?

TL;DR: I have no idea how to work with GridFS and the php-docs are of poor quality. Can at the very least, someone point out better examples/documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the full path to the file when I call $grid->storeFile().  Also, yes, I store the mime type in the metadata.  So, my call looks like this:

```
$id = $grid->storeFile($uploaded_file, 
        array(
           'ownerNodeUuid'    => $additional['nodeUuid'],
           'ownerField'       => $additional['fieldUuid'],
           'originalFilename' => $name,
           'type'             => $type,
           'size'             => $size
        ), 
        array(
           'safe' => 1
        ));
```

and this creates an entry like this:

```
db.myPrefix.files.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4ea1912af3e145731c000010"),
    "ownerNodeUuid" : "74DAB098-4A6F-4172-84AB-EDAFAA9FE22D",
    "ownerField" : "C58AD24C-7A8C-402A-BE82-2D315BC5F7C0",
    "originalFilename" : "image001.png",
    "type" : "image/png",
    "size" : 73679,
    "filename" : "/tmp/phpNhAmGK",
    "uploadDate" : "Fri Oct 21 2011 16:35:06 GMT+0100 (BST)",
    "length" : 73679,
    "chunkSize" : 262144,
    "md5" : "3e36620fdfebdf9fbf311e996a4bc46c"
}
```

, so in this case $uploaded_file = "/tmp/phpNhAmGK";

Hope that helps.  There are plenty of examples around on the web, but I agree that the PHP library documentation is sometimes a bit sparse...  It's best to think about it as a simple wrapper around the MongoDB shell functions, so the first place I look is always the MongoDB site itself, and then when I understand what something is supposed to do in MongoDB, I look for the PHP documentation for the PHP version of that functionality.

Comment: I was just about to edit the question. It seems like some kind of encoding issue messed up a char in the path and that was causing the initial problems Unfortunately, when I run my script now, "Segmentation fault" is returned, which seems to come from MongoDB, not PHP, and is probably due to something in `$extras`.

Comment: Try doing a var_dump on what you're sending to MongoDB and recreating the command in the Mongo shell - see if you get a seg fault then.  Also, see what version of MongoDB you're using and see if there are any known issues with the MongoDB PHP extension version in use (get this from phpinfo();)

Comment: You can see from my example which fields are added automatically, and which fields need to be added.  In my example, I'm actually duplicating the length property (and calling it 'size').  You need to add in mime type if you need it.  You may want to store the filename without the path for ease of use later on.

Comment: My segfault problem still occurs, but for some strange reason the files are stored anyway. I'm still annoyed though, that the php doc is so vague.I mean, since when is "The name of the file." a proper explanation for `$filename`... But thanks, your answer really helped.